Tool for generating AI-based answers to multiple questions and formatting them into a single PDF
I am looking for a reliable tool or alternative that can take a list of questions, use AI to generate answers for each question, and then compile those answers into a formatted PDF or document file. Can anyone suggest a tool that fits these requirements or share their experience with similar solutions?
